# ajax php post with sessions wont give results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I am trying to get pre set session variables through ajax and display in my modal. its like a cart. But when i try to get them there is no result at all when i read the ajax result from chrome inspect network or the modal. below is my code. what am i doing wrong here?

```
<script>
    $("#cart-button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/cart-read.php",
            success: function(data){

                  console.log(data);
                  alert(data);
                $('#modal-body').empty().append(''+data+'');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and in cart-read.php

```
if(isset($_SESSION['dices'])){
    foreach ($_SESSION['dices'] as $dice){

        $msg = $dice;

        echo json_encode($msg);

    }
}
```

session dices is an array with simple numbers. such as 4, 5, 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the following things in your code

1. Check if you have added session_start(); below after

   Try putting an **else** case to your session check,

   Try using an array to store and display the results.

   ```
   <?php
   session_start();
   $result = array();
   $msg = array();
   if(isset($_SESSION['dices'])){
   foreach ($_SESSION['dices'] as $dice){

       array_push($msg,$dice);
       }

       if(sizeof($msg) > 0)
       {
           $result['status'] = true;
           $result['message'] = $msg;
       }
       else
       {
           $result['status'] = false;
           $result['message'] = 'No values';
       }
   }
   else
   {
   $result['status'] = false;
   $result['message'] = 'Session not set';
   }

     echo json_encode($result);
   ?>
   ```

Comment: oh god. it was session_start(); dies :v